# Gradle desugaring failed, Hierarchy is incomplete

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, jar, dependencies

I am working on this project: https://github.com/muxinc/mux-stats-sdk-exoplayer/tree/min_sdk_version_fix It is Android app called demo that have dependency to a module from a same project called MuxExoPlayer which have a dependency to a MuxCore.jar library.

When I try to compile the project with minSdkVersion 16, I get desugaring issue on jar file, error:

```
Transform artifact full.jar (project :MuxExoPlayer) with DexingWithClasspathTransform
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default method desugaring of `com.mux.stats.sdk.muxstats.MuxStatsExoPlayer` failed because it's hierarchy is incomplete. The class `com.mux.stats.sdk.core.events.EventBus` is missing and it is the declared super class of `com.mux.stats.sdk.muxstats.MuxBaseExoPlayer`","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
```

When I compile with minSdkVersion 24, I do not get this error and project compile just fine.

MuxCore.jar is also built with gradle, here is the gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    sourceCompatibility = '1.7'
    targetCompatibility = '1.7'
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20180130'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.4'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
}
```

What am I missing here ?
How do I need to compile MuxCore in order to compile with android minSdkVersion 16 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and also create a ticket in Mux github repo but could not make it work... If you update the minSdk to 24 it will work...

https://github.com/muxinc/mux-stats-sdk-exoplayer/issues/19

What is working for me is: instead of adding MuxStatsExoPlayer as a module add directly all the files and classes in your app module into your project and it should work.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, thanks for the reply, I agree with your observation that was one of the things I have tried and it does work but that is not acceptable in terms of company policy, this project need to remain the java library.
Another solution would be to convert it to Android lib module (AAR) and set that module min SDK version to 16 and all is well, but again it is not an option

Comment: Oh! So I would suggest you that continue discussing the problem on the github ticket. But as far as I know those are the only options, update to minSdk 24 or copy and paste the classes into your own project... Sorry not to help you better, I am in the same situation as you =D.